# Regex to find a user UPN inside a string

Tags: c#, regex

I want to find User Principal names inside all sort of strings for a C# tool to anonymize customer specific data.

I found this one:

> (?[^@]+)@(?(?:[a-z0-9]+.)+[a-z]+)

But in a string like this:

> f-4af0-86e8-01439a0ae52a\",,\"Active\",\"10/30/2018 9:05:35
>   AM\",\"SingleSession\",\"Desktop\",,\"10/29/2018 2:35:06
>   PM\",,\"655952\",\"DOM\na010318\",\"na010318\",\"DOM\n010318\",\"S-1-5-21-2052699199-3915784498-1582209984-1157056\",\"**user.a@domain.acc.local**\",\"Primary\",\"c46b084c-6df3-47dd-9d3e-8e17f855c7fe\""

It matches the entire part before the UPN (the first space, because it matches the word I guess.

How can I re-write the regular expression to only find the e-mail/UPN within this string?

Thanks

Comment: regex for RFC822 email address:  http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: It seems to me that it's a csv file, why don't you use a csv parser?

Comment: Try `[\w\.]+@[\w\.]+` but it will break for cases that are more complex.

Comment: The simplest way: `[^"@]+@[^"]+`

Comment: Cannot use a csv parser because I'm collecting from a multitude of sources, so I read all lines as text and try to filter out any customer specific info. Thanks though!

Comment: Reading all the text on huge files will use lots of memory and make you code more complicated than necessary.  Read one line at a time is more efficient and much less complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a UPN effectively has the same format as an email address - try some of the answers from this question:

[regex extract email from strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42407785/regex-extract-email-from-strings)

The following regex works for your example:

`([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)`

https://regex101.com/r/ijG8Xr/2

Comment: That last one seems to work like it should. Do you also know how to filter out things like domain\username ? I'm very afraid for false positives there...