# How can I print only match pattern word in Terraform

Tags: regex, terraform, cpu-word, terragrunt

If i got value like

```
email = "Mark Johnson (mark@johnson.com)"
```

How can i print only word in the () and output become

```
mark@johnson.com
```

Currently I using regex but It seems doesn't work with my pattern

```
email = regex("x{(,)}", "var.email")
```

How can i solve this issue , Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42407785/regex-extract-email-from-strings

Comment: That's a strange looking pattern, and doesn't even come close to what you are after. If I may suggest something, possibly a pattern like `(?<=\()[^)]+` or a bit extended with lookahead too will do the job.

Answer (score 3):

Terrafrom used RE2 regex engine, and the [`regex`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/regex.html) function returns only the captured value if you define a capturing group in the regex pattern. It will return a list of captures if you have more than one capturing group in your pattern, but here, you need just one.

To extract all text inside parentheses:

```
> regex("[(]([^()]+)[)]", "Mark Johnson (mark@johnson.com)")
```

The `[(]` matches a `(` char, `([^()]+)` captures into Group 1 any one or more chars into Group 1, and `[)]` matches a `)` char.

To extract an email-like string from parentheses:

```
> regex("[(]([^()@[:space:]]+@[^()[:space:]]+[.][^()[:space:]]+)[)]", "Mark Johnson (mark@johnson.com)")
```

Here, `[^()@[:space:]]+` matches 1 or more chars other than `(`, `)`, `@` and whitespace.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MuaVTS/1)